# South doesn't recognize new model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

South doesn't recognize the modifications that I'm trying to make to my models.py.

This is the new model that I want to create:

```
class QuestionHistory(models.Manager):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

I'm trying to use this command in terminal:

```
python manage.py schemamigration multichoice --auto
```

But I'm receiving this message:

```
Nothing seems to have changed.
```

Comment: Is the app already under south? if not, http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#the-first-migration

Comment: Yes, the app is already under south @karthikr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inherit QuestionHistory from `models.Manager` not from `models.Model`, need to be:

```
class QuestionHistory(models.Model):
    ...
```